# How to run only failed testcases in Vector CANoe

Tags: testing, report, capl, canoe

I am executing XML test module of 182 testcases in CANoe. Wherein 2-3 random testcases are getting failed every time and those are getting passed if I run those individually. To get complete Pass test report of 182 testcases, I need to run whole module again which takes almost 16hr(with very less chances of all getting Passed).

I have tried to execute only failed testcase by unchecking other testcases in XML execution dialog but then it will create test report for only those selected testcases and marked others unexecuted. This is not helping to generate Passed test report for 182 testcases.

**Can we execute only failed testcases without disturbing results of other Passed testcases?**

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to fix the testcases?